# Refactoring in Visual studio 2010 express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, refactoring

Help or suggestion will do.

I'm installing the Visual Studio Express 2010, i know we cannot use resharper with express edition. i need know do i have any other alternate tool that i can use with visual studio Express 2010 edition.

Sameer,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Express Edition of Visual Studio do not support add-ins. As far as refactoring is concerned, Visual Studio has some [built-in refactoring functionalities](https://web.archive.org/web/20130103165052/http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/7-refactoring-methods-visual-studio-2010) which could come handy.

Answer (score 0):

The Express Edition of Visual Studio do not support add-ins. As far as refactoring is concerned, Visual Studio has some built-in refactoring functionalities which could come handy.

**The express version however does only have two refactoring functionalities:** rename and extract method, the other functionalities like encapsulate are not present.